# Фиксированное меню у таблички

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Есть табличка с данными. Слева хочу сделать меню управления этой табличкой - добавление/удаление/редактирование. Если в табличке много данных, естественно, она прокручивается, но меню всё равно должно стоять на месте.

Как такое сверстать?

Comment: `position: fixed;` или JS

Answer (score 0):

есть CSS свойство `fixed`. 
Используйте его. Примерно как-то так:

```html
<div class="menu" style="position: fixed; margin:10px;">
содержание меню                         
</div>

<table>
ваша табличка
</table>
```

Comment: если navbar-fixed-top, получиться сделать вертикальное меню слева от таблички?

Comment: пропустил слово "слева". спасибо за исправление

Comment: используйте приведенный код для решения вопроса

Comment: Подумал - сложнее получается, что скролится вся страница... Допустим, страничка большая... Таблица с меню внизу, их не видно. Теперь скролим вверх, появляется и таблица и меню... Как только табличка уходит за верний предел экрана, меню останавливается и ждёт... как меню достигло нижней части таблицы - тоже уходит вместе с таблицей...

Comment: то есть вам нужно что бы это все было в отдельном блоке? и меню и табличка?

Comment: Ну как бы да... Как описал выше...

Comment: Поведение очень похоже на вот это: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/customize/

Comment: В Вашем примере используется position:fixed, Блок всегда есть, просто он видоизменяется при прокрутке